# Error "Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use routing for the first time and followed the exact instructions from [Udemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udemy):

#### File *App.js*:

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Welcome from "./Pages/Welcome";
import Game from "./Pages/Game";
import Leaderboard from "./Pages/Leaderboard";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Route path = "/welcome">
                <Welcome />
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/game">
                <Game />
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/leaderboard">
                <Leaderboard />
            </Route>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

#### File *index.js*

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I get the following error:

> Error: A Route is only ever to be used as the child of 
> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your Route in a Routes.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 208):

Yes, in react-router-dom version 6 it is a bit different. Please look as the sample below.

*[React Router tutorial](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/tutorial.md)*

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import Expenses from "./routes/expenses";
import Invoices from "./routes/invoices";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="expenses" element={<Expenses />} />
      <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

Answer (score 51):

There was a fairly decent change between versions 5 and 6 of `react-router-dom`. It appears that the Udemy course/tutorial is using version 5 where all you needed was a `Router` to provide a routing context and `Route` components just needed to be rendered within this context. In version 6, however, the `Route` components now need to be rendered within a `Routes` component (*which is an upgrade from the v5 `Switch` component*).

[Introducing `Routes`](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#introducing-routes)

> One of the most exciting changes in v6 is the powerful new `<Routes>`
> element. This is a pretty significant upgrade from v5's `<Switch>`
> element with some important new features including relative routing
> and linking, automatic route ranking, and nested routes and layouts.

The error message is pretty clear, wrap your `Route` components in a `Routes` component. The routes also don't take children (*other than other `Route` components in the case of nested routes*), they render the components ***as JSX*** on the new `element` prop.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/welcome" element={<Welcome />} />
        <Route path="/game" element={<Game />} />
        <Route path="/leaderboard" element={<Leaderboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The problem is your react-router-dom version.

Probably it's 5.1 or higher.

You can try (in terminal):

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.3.0
```

And then your code will be OK. Or you better rebuild your code according to new react-router-dom.

Comment: Guys if you are working on following some tutorials. I kindly suggest you install `npm install react-router-dom@5.3.0` , After you master **routing** you can use the latest version

Answer (score 11):

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';


import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { Home } from './components/screens/Home';
import { Login } from './components/screens/Login';
import { Profile } from './components/screens/Profile';
import { Signup } from './components/screens/Signup';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />\
    </Routes>




    </BrowserRouter>


  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you could elaborate, make your answer richer. You could explain the problems you devised, how your code solves them, and highlight the changes that make it work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

In the latest version of React, 'Switch' is replaced with '**Routes**' and 'component' is replaced with '**element**'

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsNSy.png)

Answer (score 7):

I think there are many problems that can lead to that issue.

1. *react-router-dom* version 6 no longer supports the use of components directly. Use an element to specify the component you route.
2. Route has to be a child of Routes

Use the simple snippet.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Homescreen from './screens/Homescreen';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <BrowserRouter>      
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/home' element={<Homescreen/>} />
        </Routes>
    
      </BrowserRouter>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to wrap your routes by `Routes`:

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Welcome from "./Pages/Welcome";
import Game from "./Pages/Game";
import Leaderboard from "./Pages/Leaderboard";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path = "/welcome">
                <Welcome />
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/game">
                <Game />
            </Route>
            <Route path = "/leaderboard">
                <Leaderboard />
            </Route>
           </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You have to add Browser router as well

Comment: @BilalYaqoob as he already wrapped <app/> by Browser router in index.js, so it does not require to add Browser router in app.js

Answer (score 5):

The problem right here is that you are using React v5. Since React  v6, several changes were included in Router.

So now, to make it work, and as your error message says, you need to wrap your Route element inside a Routes element (Routes now is the equivalent, but an improved version of Switch element). Also, you need to add an "element" prop that accepts [JSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#JSX) instead of wrapping inside the Route element.

So, to make it work, you need to import all these elements like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

That being said, your code should look like this:

```
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Welcome/>}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" element={<Game />}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/" element={<Leaderboard />}>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because you are using version 6 or higher of react-router-dom.
Try:`npm i react-router-dom@5.2.0`
And it should work.

Answer (score 3):

In the newer version of `react-router-dom`, we need to nest the `Route` inside the `Routes`. Also, `component` and `exact` have been removed in newer version.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue and solve it.
Though I am using

```
react-router-dom@6
```

So I had to modify `app.js` and `index.js` like below

in **`index.js`**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


<React.StrictMode>
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

and **`app.js`**

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

  function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
        <main className="py-3">
          <Container>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} exact/>
            </Routes>
          </Container>
        </main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

according to official [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score 1):

### Now, React uses React Router version 6

For React Router version 6, your *index.js* file is correct:

#### File *index.js*:

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But your *App.js* file is not correct for React Router version 6, so this is the correct one below:

I changed three parts as shown below:

#### File *App.js*

```js
  // 1. "Routes" is imported
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Welcome from "./Pages/Welcome";
import Game from "./Pages/Game";
import Leaderboard from "./Pages/Leaderboard";

function App() {
    return (
        <div> // 2. With "<Routes></Routes>", surround "3 <Route /> tags"
            <Routes> // 3. Put an element with a component to each "<Route />"
                <Route path = "/welcome" element={<Welcome />} />
                <Route path = "/game" element={<Game />} />
                <Route path = "/leaderboard" element={<Leaderboard />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

in your index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")); //where App must rendered in real DOM?in root
root.render(<App />); //jsx code is a special syntax that browser not undrestand it!
```

and in your App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AllMeetupsPage from "./pages/AllMeetups";
import NewMeetupPage from "./pages/NewMeetup";
import FavoritesPage from "./pages/Favorites";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<AllMeetupsPage />} />
          <Route path="/new-meetup" element={<NewMeetupPage />} />
          <Route path="/favorites" element={<FavoritesPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

on react version 6,  2 major changes are

1. New Route should be under Routes
2. Route has a property element in which you need to set your component.

   ```
     <Routes> (1)
       <Route path="/welcome" element={<Welcome />} /> (2)
       <Route path="/game" element={<Game />} />
       <Route path="/leaderboard" element={<Leaderboard />} />
     </Routes>
   ```

Ignore small braces and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```html
<div>
  <Header />
</div>
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Try to wrap your routes by Routes:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the element option to set your component instead of nesting it into the route tags. Then wrap all the routes with `<Routes></Routes>`.

Do not forget to add Routes to your imports

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Welcome from "./Pages/Welcome";
import Game from "./Pages/Game";
import Leaderboard from "./Pages/Leaderboard";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Routes>
              <Route path = "/welcome" element={<Welcome />}/>
              <Route path = "/game" element={<Game />}/>
              <Route path = "/leaderboard" element={<Leaderboard />}/>
            </Routes>          
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but there is another way to do nested routes straight from javascript.

first import

```
import { useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
```

secondly, declare your routes. Here is a quick example

```
function App() {

return useRoutes([
{
  path: "/",
  element: <Example/>
},
{
  path: "/contact",
  element: <Example/>
}]);
```

}

so now you can have unlimited nested components doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
        index.js
        
        import React from "react";
        import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
        import "./index.css";
        import App from "./App";
        import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
        import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
        import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
        
        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
        root.render(
          <React.StrictMode>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
          </React.StrictMode>
        );
        
        reportWebVitals();
    
    import "./App.css";
    import React from "react";
    import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    import Nav from "./Nav";
    import Home from "./Home";
    import About from "./About";
    import Winner from "./Winner";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Nav />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />        
            <Route path="/winner" element={<Winner />} />        
        </Routes>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;


Nav.js

import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


function Nav() 
{
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/home"> Home </Link>
      <br />
      <Link to="/about"> About </Link>
      <br />
      <Link to="/winner"> Winner List </Link>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Nav;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to fix the version issues:

App.js File:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Welcome from "./Pages/Welcome";
import Game from "./Pages/Game";
import Leaderboard from "./Pages/Leaderboard";

function App() {
  return (<div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
            <Route path = "/Welcome" element={< Welcome/>}/>
            <Route path = "/Game" element={< Game/>}/>
            <Route path = "/LeaderBoard" element={< LeaderBoard/>}/>
           </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```