# react router to be used as the child of <Routes> element error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created a react app and use react-router-dom for navigation. WHen i wrapp the app.js with BrowseRouter the following error shows.

```
Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
```

the following is my App.js

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

    function App() {
      return (
     
     <BrowserRouter>
     
        <div className="App">
    
          <Header/>
    
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home/>
          </Route>
            
          <Footer/>
      </div>  
      </BrowserRouter> 
      );
    }
```

Comment: What isn't clear in the error message. The `Route` components need to be wrapped in a `Routes` component. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832889/8690857

Comment: tried to wrap it with Routes as well. still the same error

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing when you try to resolve this by wrapping the routes in a `Routes` component?

Comment: `
<Router>
 
    <div className="App">
<Header/>

  <Routes>
      
      <Route exact path="/">
      <Home/>
   </Route>

      </Routes>
     <Footer/>
  </div>  

  </Router>
`

Comment: Try sticking with <BrowserRouter/>

Comment: Tried using <BrowserRouter/> as well. still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap all the `Route` components in a `Routes` component, and render the components for each route on the `element` prop.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />

          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-to-be-used-as-the-child-of-routes-element-error]

Answer (score 1):

```
    import {BrowserRouter, Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

    function App() {
      return (
     
    
     
        <div className="App">
    
          <Header/>
     <BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home/>
          </Route>
</Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
          <Footer/>
      </div>  
       
      );
    }
```

or in React-router-dom version 6 :

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route,Switch,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

    function App() {
      return (
     
    
     
        <div className="App">
    
          <Header/>
     <BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home/>
          </Route>
</Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
          <Footer/>
      </div>  
       
      );
    }
```

Comment: React-router-dom version 6 doesn't export a `Switch` component, it was replaced by the `Routes` component.

Comment: then you can use Routes instead