# A<Route>is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your<Route>in a<Routes> .Getting this error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Users from "./users/pages/Users";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
    
      <Route path="/">
        <Users />
      </Route>
   
    </Router>
    
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried replacing router with routes still getting same error.

Comment: What error? Please add information to your question and choose a more precise and shorter title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832748/error-error-a-route-is-only-ever-to-be-used-as-the-child-of-routes-element)

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

1. All `Route` components can only be rendered by a parent `Routes` component, or another `Route` component in the case of nested routes.
2. Only other `Route` components are valid children of the `Route` component, so `Users` can't be rendered as a child component.

## Solution

1. Wrap the `Route` component in a `Routes` component.
2. Render `Users` as the `element` of its `Route`.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Users from "./users/pages/Users";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Users />} />
        ... other routes ...
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap `Route` elements in a `Routes` element

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Users from "./users/pages/Users";

const App = () => { 
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Users />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  ); 
};
```